# How do I get the selected text from a WordEditor Object and change it's color?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to use the `WordEditor` object to modify the color of the selected text (Outlook VBA) but i'm unable to find documentation or examples on how to do it. Any ideas?

I don't want to use the HTML editor, i need a solution for `WordEditor`.

I tried debuging the code and using OutlookSpy, but everytime i go into WordEditor.Content my outlook freezes and restarts :(.

Using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - I found something that works. Ugly, but works:

```
Sub EmphesizeSelectedText(color As Long)
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set msg = insp.CurrentItem
        If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

            Set document = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set rng = document.Application.Selection

            With rng.font
                .Bold = True
                .color = color
            End With
        End If
    End If
    Set insp = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set hed = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Eventually I found a reference that **WordEditor** returns a **`Document`** object. From there it was 2 hrs of going over MSDN's very slow web-help to find out that to get the selected text i needed to go up one level to the **`Application`**. 
Important note - changing `rng.Style.Font` did not do what i wanted it to do, it changed the entire document, when i started using the `with rng.font` my problem was solved (Thanks to Excel's marco recording abilities for showing me the correct syntax)

Comment: This answer is really hard to use without `Option Explicit` - I think this should solve a similar problem I have, but without all variables being declared, it is not at all clear if it applies..

Comment: @enderland - I'm not familiar with ` Option Explicit` - what is it and how is it related to the problem?

Comment: Option Explicit is an ancient BASIC construct that instructs the parser to insist the EVERY variable be declared (dimensioned) and assigned a type. Had the module from which the above example was copied had an Option Explicit statement, it would have complained rather loudly the "rng" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are in German

```
Option Explicit
'Sub EmphesizeSelectedText(color As Long)
Sub EmphesizeSelectedText()
    Dim om_msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oi_insp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim ws_selec As Word.Selection

    Dim wd_Document As Word.Document
    Dim str_test As String

    Dim lng_color As Long
    lng_color = 255

    'Zugriff auf aktive E-Mail
    Set oi_insp = Application.ActiveInspector()
    'Überprüft ob es sich wirklich um eine E-Mail handelt
    If oi_insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set om_msg = oi_insp.CurrentItem
        If oi_insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            ' es gibt noch "olEditorHTML", "olEditorRTF", "olEditorText" und "olEditorWord"
            ' ist bei mir aber immer "olEditorWord" (= 4) - egal was ich im E-Mail Editor auswähle

            ' Set wd_Document = om_msg.Getinspector.WordEditor ' macht das gleiche wie nächste Zeile
            Set wd_Document = oi_insp.WordEditor
            Set ws_selec = wd_Document.Application.Selection
            str_test = ws_selec.Text
            Debug.Print ws_selec.Text
            ws_selec.Text = "foo bar"
            If om_msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatPlain Then
                ' auch wenn om_msg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ist, kann oi_insp.EditorType = olEditorWord sein
                ' doch dann gehen Formatierungen nicht -> Error !!!
                With ws_selec.Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .color = lng_color ' = 255 = red
                    .color = wdColorBlue
                End With
            End If
            ws_selec.Text = str_test
        End If
    End If

    Set oi_insp = Nothing
    Set ws_selec = Nothing
    Set om_msg = Nothing
    Set wd_Document = Nothing
End Sub
```

Verweise: (I do not know how it is called in the english version)

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library

Gruz $3v|\|

Comment: Verweise = References.

Answer (score 0):

an other example:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Test_It()
    Dim om_Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oi_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wd_Doc As Word.Document
    Dim wd_Selection As Word.Selection
    Dim wr_Range As Word.Range

    Dim b_return As Boolean
    Dim str_Text As String
    str_Text = "Hello World"

    'Zugriff auf aktive E-Mail
    Set oi_Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set om_Item = oi_Inspector.CurrentItem
    Set wd_Doc = oi_Inspector.WordEditor

    'Zugriff auf Textmarkierung in E-Mail
    Set wd_Selection = wd_Doc.Application.Selection
    wd_Selection.InsertBefore str_Text

    'Zugriff auf 'virtuelle' Markierung
    'wr_Range muss auf das ganze Dokument gesetzt werden !
    Set wr_Range = wd_Doc.Content
    'Suche in E-Mail Text
    With wr_Range.Find
        .Forward = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = "#%*%#"
    End With
    b_return = True
    Do While b_return
        b_return = wr_Range.Find.Execute
        If b_return Then
            ' Es wurde gefunden
            str_Text = wr_Range.Text
            'schneide den Anfangstext und das Ende ab
            'str_TextID = Mid$(str_TextID, 11, Len(str_TextID) - 12)
            MsgBox ("Es wurde noch folgender Schlüssel gefunden:" & vbCrLf & str_Text)
        End If
    Loop
    'aktiv Range ändern
    'wr_Range muss auf das ganze Dokument gesetzt werden !
    Set wr_Range = wd_Doc.Content
    wr_Range.Start = wr_Range.Start + 20
    wr_Range.End = wr_Range.End - 20
    'Text formatieren
    With wr_Range.Font
        .ColorIndex = wdBlue
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = True
        .Underline = wdUnderlineDotDashHeavy
    End With

    'Freigeben der verwendeten Variablen
    Set oi_Inspector = Nothing
    Set om_Item = Nothing
    Set wd_Doc = Nothing
    Set wd_Selection = Nothing
    Set wr_Range = Nothing
End Sub
```

Gruz $3v|\|