# Outlook VBA Replace inline object with text

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have an email message in my Inbox which contains an inline object (e.g., an image). I want to remove it, and insert text at the same point in the email.

I tried with two methods:

1. Dealing with objects with `Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment`. I tried using the `Position` method, but *the problem is that it always returns `0`, regardless of the position of the object (and whether it is inline or in the "attachments bar")*.
2. Dealing with objects with `Dim shp As Word.InlineShape`. I could determine the location of `shp`, with `Set shpRange = objDoc.Range(shp.Range.Characters.First.Start, shp.Range.Characters.Last.End)` (and `Dim objDoc As Word.Document`; thanks to [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23830430/2707864)). I tried modifying `objDoc` in three ways.

   2.1. `shpRange.InsertAfter "Replacement Text 1"`.

   2.2. `shpRange.Text = "Replacement Text 2"`.

   2.3. `objDoc.Characters(1).InsertBefore "New Text"`.

   *The problem is that none of them modifies the email.*

So far, I have used method 1 with `objMsg.HTMLBody = <mytext> + objMsg.HTMLBody`, then `objMsg.Save`. But this adds text at the beginning.

PS: when one replies to an email with an inline object, it is sometimes replaced with text at the location of the object (I could not ascertain when this is done). Perhaps MS does not provide functionality for accomplishing the same.

---

**EDIT (Extra details, originally not included to avoid tl;dr)**

Notes:

1. The code I am currently using is based on [a post by Nicola Delfino](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicold/archive/2006/11/26/how-to-remove-attachments-from-outlook-2007-emails-easily.aspx). It uses  `objMsg.HTMLBody`, see below.
   On the up side, it finds most inline attachments/objects (some are missed), and all in the "attachments bar" (I do not know the official name for it).
   On the down side, it cannot discriminate inline from "bar-attached" items, and it cannot get the location of inline objects found. So I had it add text only at the beginning of the mail body.
2. I see the problem with any email I tried. For instance, I have created an email, and inserted a picture with `Insert -> Picture`. After sending the email, I worked with the email in my `Sent Items` folder.
3. I am attaching an image of a sample email that I used for testing.
   [image]
4. It might be the case that `objMsg.HTMLBody` could never work, and that I should go with `WordEditor`, after reading [this official page for Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_UsingWordEditor):
   "***17.5 Using WordEditor***
   The Outlook object model itself provides no direct way to determine the position of the cursor in an item body. However, since the editor for every item body (except on “sticky notes” and distribution lists) is a special version of Microsoft Word, you can use Word techniques not only to add text at the insertion point, but also to add formatted text anywhere in the item, or even to add a picture."
5. Possibly relevant links:

[How do I get the selected text from a WordEditor Object and change it's color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361293/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-a-wordeditor-object-and-change-its-color)

[Deletion of InlineShape does not work for RTF mails](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c0f2193-0497-461c-9725-f941ca0a24da/deletion-of-inlineshape-does-not-work-for-rtf-mails?forum=outlookdev)

My code:

```
    Public Sub StripAttachments()
        'Put in the folder location you want to save attachments to
        Dim strFolder As String
        strFolder = "removed_attachments"
        Dim ilocation As String
        ilocation = GetSpecialFolder(&H5) & "\" & strFolder ' CSIDL_MY_DOCUMENTS As Long = &H5"
        On Error Resume Next
        ilocation = ilocation & "\"

        ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
        Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
        Set objOL = Application
        ' Get the collection of selected objects.
        Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
        Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

        'Dim objMsg As Object
        Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        ' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist, save them to the selected
        ' folder and strip them from the item.
        For Each objMsg In objSelection
            ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
            If (objMsg.Class = olMail) Then
                Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
                Set objInsp = objMsg.GetInspector
            Dim objDoc As Word.Document
            Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor

                ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
                Dim objAttachments As Outlook.attachments
                Set objAttachments = objMsg.attachments
                Dim lngCount As Long
                lngCount = objAttachments.Count
                If lngCount > 0 Then
                    ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items from a collection. Otherwise,
                    ' the loop counter gets confused and only every other item is removed.
                    Dim strFile As String
                    strFile = ""

                    Dim I As Long
                    For I = lngCount To 1 Step -1
                        ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
                        ' Get the file name.
                        Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
                        Set objAttachment = objAttachments.item(I)

                        Dim strHTML As String
                        strHTML = "<li><a href=" & Chr(34) & "file:" & ilocation & objAttachment.FileName & Chr(34) _
                          & ">" & objAttachment.FileName & "</a><br>" & vbCrLf
                        strFile = strFile & strHTML

                        Dim attPos As Long
                        attPos = objAttachment.Position
                        ' Save the attachment as a file
                        objAttachment.SaveAsFile (ilocation & objAttachments.item(I))
                        ' Remove the attachment
                        objAttachment.Delete
                        ' Replace with text and hyperlink
                        'strFile = "Attachments removed from the message and backed up to [<a href='" & ilocation & "'>" & ilocation & "</a>]:<br><ul>" & strFile & "</ul><hr><br><br>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Next I

                    strFile = "Attachments removed from the message and backed up to [<a href='" & ilocation & "'>" & ilocation & "</a>]:<br><ul>" & strFile & "</ul><hr><br><br>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    objDoc.Characters(1).InsertBefore strFile  ' Does nothing!
                    objMsg.HTMLBody = strFile + objMsg.HTMLBody
                    objMsg.Save
                Else
                    msgbox ("No attachments were found in the selected email")
                End If
            Else
                msgbox ("Selection is not of type olMail")
            End If
        Next

    ExitSub:
        Set objAttachments = Nothing
        Set objMsg = Nothing
        Set objSelection = Nothing
        Set objOL = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have found the reason why I was not able to modify the `Word.Document`. I have to use `objDoc.UnProtect` (I was not getting an error due to `On Error Resume Next`). Now I can modify `objDoc`. I still have to find how to save shapes to disk, with a suitable file name. [This](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/144880-Macro-needed-to-find-embedded-MS-Word-graphics-and-save-out-to-a-file-name) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WordEditor` basically is a word `Document` if I remember correctly, so you should be able to do something similar to (tested in Word, may need tweak for Outlook), assuming an object variable like `doc` to represent the `Document`:

**Revised & tested in Outlook 2010**

```
Dim shp as InlineShape
Dim doc as Object `Word.Document
Dim shpRange as Object `Word.Range
Const wdInlineShapePicture as Long = 3
Const wdInlineShapesEmbeddedOLEObject as Long = 1
Set doc = objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
For Each shp In doc.InlineShapes
    Select Case shp.Type 
        Case wdInlineShapePicture, wdInlineShapesEmbeddedOLEObject
            '## Assign a range object with the text position of the shape
            Set shpRange = doc.Range(shp.Range.Characters.First.Start, _
                                  shp.Range.Characters.Last.End)
            '## Replace the shape with text:
            shpRange.Text = "Replacement Text"
        Case Else
            '## Do something else for other shape types, etc.
      End Select

Next
```

Here is an example macro to process incoming mailitems, and replace the embedded images with text.  Note the need to `UnProtect` the document:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As MailItem
    '## Word objects, using late-binding (or enable reference to MS Word)
    Dim shp As Object 'Word.InlineShape
    Dim doc As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim shpRange As Object 'Word.Range
    '## Establish some word constants for use with late-binding
    Const wdInlineShapePicture As Long = 3
    Const wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject As Long = 1
    Const wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture As Long = 4

    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set m = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(arr(i))
        Set doc = m.GetInspector.WordEditor
        doc.UnProtect
        For Each shp In doc.InlineShapes
            Select Case shp.Type
                Case wdInlineShapePicture, _
                     wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject, _
                     wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture

                    '## Assign a range object with the text position of the shape
                    Set shpRange = doc.Range(shp.Range.Characters.First.Start, _
                                              shp.Range.Characters.Last.End)
                    '## Replace the shape with text:
                    shpRange.Text = "Replacement Text"
                Case Else

            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try revision above... `.HasPicture` is property of Shape objects in PowerPoint, my mistake. You can test based on `shp.Type = 3`.

Comment: The test works, but the images are not replaced (as mentioned before).

Comment: Hmmm that is odd because it is working when I test it in Outlook -- does the replacement text appear in the email or no?  If it does, you could remove the shape with `shp.Delete`.

Comment: `shp.Delete` is not deleting the Shape. The way I delete it is with `objAttachment.Delete` (`objAttachment` is of type `Outlook.Attachment`).

Comment: @sancho.s this would have been very helpful to know beforehand... Please update your original question to include the code you are *currently* using, if you would like any further assistance.  When you talk about an "inline image", I do not think of "attachment"... the solution I have currently posted applies to inline images, not attachments...

Comment: @sancho.s can you also describe **how** you're attaching the file? When I try to attach a file, it always appears as an attachment and never as an inline shape -- a screenshot or two might also be helpful to assist you.  Cheers.

Comment: I mean to process incoming email, so they can contain these `InlineShape`s of may different `Type`s (which I do not know if they are at the same time `Outlook.Attachment`s). Moreover, the idea is to save them to disk prior to replacing by inline text. [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c0f2193-0497-461c-9725-f941ca0a24da/deletion-of-inlineshape-does-not-work-for-rtf-mails?forum=outlookdev) appears to point at the same, but I could not understand what the solution found was.

Comment: revision above probably should handle embedded objects (I have only tested the revision in Word because I would have to connect to VPN/etc. to use my Outlook.  I modify that code to work for Pictures and Embedded OLE Objects, but I have not tested Outlook event handler yet.

Comment: OK, tested above on an outlook Calendar/Meeting item, and I think it will work.

Comment: David, thanks for your dedication. The problem is not that the `If`condition evaluated to `False`. The problem is that `shpRange.Text = "Replacement Text"` does not alter the email. I have thoroughly revised my post according to your answer, your comments, and what I have tested following them.

Comment: Found the reason why I was not being able to alter the email. I had to `Unprotect` it. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, I am finally online and able to test in Outlook and I see the "protection" issue. Glad you are able to resolve this. Do consider upvoting or accepting this if it has helped solve your problem!

Comment: No worries. I am going to revise my answer to include the `Unprotect` so that hopefully this can be useful to others with similar queries in the future!

Comment: I actually meant to replace all inline attachments (not stated in my original post, but now fixed). At the time of posting, I was dealing with images. So, for my particular case, the `Case`s you selected would be changed. Perhaps I do not even need to ask anything, just replace every `InlineShape`.

Comment: Yes, if you need to replace *ALL* inline shapes, then you would not really need to use the `Select Case` statements.

Comment: I found some strange result. For a case at hand, `shp.Range.Characters.First.Start` = 1412, `shp.Range.Characters.Last.Start` = 1412, `shp.Range.Characters.First.End` = 1488, `shp.Range.Characters.Last.End` = 1488, and `shpRange.Characters.Count` = 1. Is there an easy explanation for this?

Comment: Does it not work in these cases? (when I do some quick testing in word, I am able to replace a range defined by a *single* character. I don't have any example at hand of an inline shape that takes such a range. If you can post an example to dropbox or google docs, perhaps I can look at it.