# Accessing inline and bar attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

An Outlook message can contain attachments (see fig., borrowed from http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/2011/01/28/email-attachments-in-the-body-of-outlook-messages/):

- A set of inline attachments (*IA*, left fig.), understood as any object besides text
- A set of bar attachments (*BA*, right fig.)

[image]

I have several questions on accessing them via VBA. They are cross-related, so it is worth posting them all together.

1. **Is there a comprehensive way to access *IA*?**

   In many cases, I found that the collection `MailItem.Inspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes` (*IS*) is *IS=IA*. Is this always true?
2. **Is there a comprehensive way to access *BA*?**

   In many cases, I found that the collection `MailItem.attachments` (*AT*) is *AT=IA+BA*. But I have found exceptions: emails with nonempty *IA* and empty *AT*. Some use of *AT* might perhaps help, even with what I found.
3. **Having a reference to an item in *IA*, is there any way of knowing if there is a corresponding item in *AT* (there may be not, according to #2), and if so identify it, *IA*->*AT*?**
4. Reversing the question in #3:

   **Having a reference to an item in *AT*, is there any way of inquiring if it is an `InlineShape`, and if so knowing which item in *IA* it corresponds to, *AT*->*IA*?**
5. **Is there any way of establishing the connections *BA*<->*AT*, similarly as in questions #3 and #4 for *IA*<->*AT*?**

PS: I am using Outlook 2010, and according to http://www.msoutlook.info/question/261 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222330 that may bring about different results from Outlook 2007, etc.

Comment: Have you tried creating a collection/dictionary of both `InlineShapes` and `Attachments`? Then, you should be able to easily compare whether the items in one exist in the other.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I don't follow you. Those two collections already exist. I do not know how what methods/properties to use to "easily compare whether the items in one exist in the other". An answer to this point would be a good starter for the rest of the question.

Comment: Create them as in assign then to a `collection` or `dictionary` object variable.  The dictionary in particular has an `exists` method which returns Boolean value true/false.

Comment: Or, perhaps this: If your true objective is simply to save "space" (i.e., the total size of all messages in your Outlook), would not a better approach be to simply *archive* old and/or large messages? This preserves their contents so that you may always access them again, later if needed. If you remove them, there's no getting them back.

Comment: Can you provide an example email `.msg` file (uploaded to Google or Dropbox) which has this condition you describe: *email has 12 `InlineShapes`, 7 of them with `shp.Type=4` (same as before). These would not be actual attachments, but links. `Attachments` has 4 items, linked to by the 7 `InlineShapes` (some are linked more than once).*

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that... Corporate issues.

Comment: You can't create a purely *sample* MSG file which is structured as you describe? That is part of "creating a minimum example that allows others to replicate your problem conditions" which is expected of questions asked here on SO. Without it, I'm not sure anyone can be of much more assistance.  I've tried to answer *all* of your questions -- what is lacking or unsatisfactory at this point?

Comment: @DavidZemens - Thanks. I agree 100% in that a sample is needed, and I mean to post it. It will only take a (hopefully short) while.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I see you tried to answer. 
Your answer was helpful (I thus upvoted) for my further extensive testing (yet to be posted).
On the other hand, it left out at least the cases I encountered (thus, not yet ok for closing the question).
Unfortunately, I *suspect* there are quite a few combinations of `InlineShape.Type`, `attachment.Type`, `MailItem.BodyFormat` (etc.?) that have to be dealt with separately. We simply appear to have hit different cases. I wouldn't mean for anyone to take care of all of them upon my request, but help is most welcome. So, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

> **Is there a comprehensive way to access IA?** In many cases, I found that the collection MailItem.Inspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes (IS) is IS=IA. Is this always true?

**NO**.  `InlineShapes` may contain items that you would not likely consider "attachments" *per se*, for instance, a corporate logo embedded in your signature, etc. will appear as an `InlineShape` which is not an "attachment" (although plain text email may include this *as* an attachment...)

Inline "Attachments" (inserted as object | create from file, for example) appear as `Type = wdInlineShapePicture` and they do not have an `OLEFormat` property (which surprises me...)

> **Is there a comprehensive way to access BA?** 
>   In many cases, I found that the collection MailItem.attachments (AT) is AT=IA+BA. But I have found exceptions: emails with nonempty IA and empty AT. Some use of AT might perhaps help, even with what I found.

Per my second comment, above, the inline shape "attachments" appear as `wdInlineShapePicture` but I believe they are treated as "attachments" in a roundabout way. Iterating the attachments collection you may notice items with generic names like `"image002.png"` I believe these are essentially "linked" through a metadata file (which may also show as an attachment item `"oledata.mso"`, to another generically named attachment (like `"image001.wmz"`.  **None of these** attachments, which **are** part of the `.Attachments` collection, will appear as a "bar attachment".

[image]

The above screenshot comes from this email where I created a dictionary object to store the attachments by name (key). This email has 2 "bar attachments" and 2 "inline attachments".  Note that the "bar attachments" are represented by their real "name", whereas the "inline attachments" are split in to the wmz/png files.

[image]

> Having a reference to an item in IA, is there any way of knowing if there is a corresponding item in AT (there may be not, according to #2), and if so identify it, IA->AT?

I don't believe so. The `"oledata.mso"` file is not something that you can read or parse, as far as I'm aware, and this seems to be the only thing that connects the wmz/png files.

> Reversing the question in #3: 
>   **Having a reference to an item in AT, is there any way of inquiring if it is an InlineShape, and if so knowing which item in IA it corresponds to, AT->IA?**

No. As far as I can tell there is no "correspondence" between the inline shapes and the attachments. Even if you were to insert the *same* file as both an Attachment *and* an Object/InlineShape, these are separate and distinct items.

Here is another example email:

[image]

And the corresponding items in `Attachments` collection:

[image]

> **Is there any way of establishing the connections BA<->AT**

Based on my research, **possibly**.

You can examine the HTML source of the email body, and parse out the inline shapes. Below you can see that the png/wmz from the last screenshot are present.

[image]

If you store **ALL** attachments in a dictionary object (assume `m` is a `MailItem` object):

```
Dim dictAttachments as Object
Set dictAttachments = CreateOBject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim attch As Attachments
Dim att as Attachment 
Dim s as Integer

    s = 0
    Set attch = m.Attachments

    For Each att In attch

        Set dictAttachments(att.DisplayName) = att
        s = s + 1
    Next
```

Then if you have identified the png/wmz from the HTML Source, you can *remove* them from the `dictAttachments` object using the `.Remove` method.

```
dictAttachments.Remove("image001.wmz") 'etc.
```

Then, the dictionary object will contain **only** the "Bar Attachments".

The trouble with this (I have tried to do this now...) is that I'm not able to find a way to parse the HTML (using an HTMLFile object) to get the PNG -- it's in a part of the HTMLBody which is essentially commented out/conditionally rendered and so it does not respond to `getElementsByTagName` method, etc.

While I would always prefer to work with the HTML/XML objects (it's usually a bad idea to try and parse HTML with normal string functions), this may be a necessary exception.  You could do something simply like:

```
Dim itm as Variant
For each itm in dictAttachments.Keys()
    If Instr(1, m.HtmlBody, "cid:" & itm & "@") > 0 Then
        dictAttachments.Remove(itm)
    End If
Next
'Ignore the oledata.mso, too:
If dictAttachments.Exists("oledata.mso") Then dictAttachments.Remove("oledata.mso")
```

Now the dictionary ONLY contains the "Bar Attachment(s)"

[image]

> **Is there any way of establishing the connections BA<->AT, similarly as in questions #3 and #4 for IA<->AT?**

I don't think there is any connection that you could possibly make. They are separate items and treated separately. Even when they are the *same* file, there's just no information in the `InlineShape` which would be useful for attempting to do this.

### **Email in HTML Format**

All of the above is for HTML format emails. In the case of HTML mail, the problem is not so much in the `Attachments` but rather a limitation of the `InlineShapes` and `InlineShape` objects in that context.

### **Email in RTF Format**

In the case of RTF mailbody, rather than being split png/wmz files, the attchment does appear *by name* in the `Attachments` collection, the other item 2 is actually a JPG as part of my signature.

[image]

HOWEVER, you will be able to observe that *attachments* in RTF have an `OLEFormat` property which and more specifically they have an `OLEFormat.ClassType = "Outlook.FileAttach"`

So you may be able to do something simple, like:

```
Select case m.BodyFormat 
    Case olFormatRichText
        For each shp in doc.InlineShapes
            If Not shp.OleFormat Is Nothing Then
                If shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Outlook.FileAttach" Then
                    'Do something here
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Case olFormatHTML
        ' Do something like the example above for HTML
    Case olFormatPlainText
        ' Do something different, if needed, for plain text emails
    Case olFormatUnspecified
        ' not sure what to do here and it's not really my problem to figure out...
End Select
```

Now, given it as part of `InlineShapes`, I don't think you can "connect" it to a specific item in the `Attachments` collection. You will be better suited to simply iterate the `Attachments` collection.

Note: In my example (a very simple one) the two dictionaries/collections appear to be indexed the same way, but I would caution against assuming this will always be the case. So while you *may* be able to delete by index position, I am not sure that is a safe/reliable assumption.

It should not be possible in RTF format to have an empty `Attachments` collection and an "Inline Attachment".

Comment: I will split comments to different parts of your interesting post. I would consider "attachment" any objects besides text, and I meant to work with them. In agreement with this criterion, I found corporate logos belonging to both `InlineShapes` and `Attachments`. So even if the answer to #1 is NO (see my comment below #2), I think the explanation would be different; a specification of cases where *IS* = *IA* is broken would be most clarifying.

Comment: The `InlineShapes` collection will *always* contain *all* of the "Inline Attachments" and possibly additional shapes/embeds.  IS=IA if and only if there are no additional shapes/embeds.

Comment: Regarding the connection IA<->AT, I did not mean attaching the same item twice, but only once, inline. Such an item would still be present in both `InlineShapes` and `Attachments` (at least some times). For a given item in `InlineShapes`, I would like to know which item in `Attachments` refers to the same object. I guess you misinterpreted the question.

Comment: No, I understand the question well enough, and if you have read my answer, I explain how the inline shape is represented by actually *two* attachment items, one is a .png and another is a .wmz.

Comment: If you have observed otherwise, you will need to supply some further examples -- including steps required to recreate the conditions you're observing and perhaps even more importantly, some *code* which validates what you think you're *seeing* is actually happening within the `MailItem` object.

Comment: Also, as a matter of etiquette you should probably not accuse people of "not understanding the question" in such a flippant manner; it comes off as very condescending and rude.

Comment: I checked two different emails (both received, none composed by myself, so I wouldn't know how were `InlineShapes` added).
One of them has several `InlineShapes` (I use `shp` as a reference), with `shp.Type`=4 (=`wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture` according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213850%28v=office.12%29.aspx)), and empty `Attachments`. **A key property** appears to be `shp.LinkFormat`. In this case, all `shp.LinkFormat`s are URLs.

Comment: The other email has 12 `InlineShapes`, 7 of them with `shp.Type`=4 (same as before). These would not be actual attachments, but links. `Attachments` has 4 items, linked to by the 7 `InlineShapes` (some are linked more than once).
This provides a specific example of when *IS* <> *IA*.

Comment: I would sincerely not see a suggestion (true or not) of "misinterpreting a question" as an accusation, or rude, by any means. I never took it that way when received. This being a case of a widely different point of view, please take my apologies. I also acknowledge your usual good will in providing thorough answers.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that `LinkFormat` is a key property. While it may be key in that particular case, I would suspect that most attachments would not have any value for that property.  What is your email format: HTML, Plain Text, or RTF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57708/discussion-between-david-zemens-and-sancho-s).

Comment: have you had a chance to make an example email file that recreates some of the condition's you're trying to isolate?

Comment: What Outlook version do you have? Please see the PS in the edited OP.

Comment: 2010, and without an example e-mail which replicates the condition you describe, nor steps to recreate such a condition, I'm not looking at this any further.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a large number of possible cases, depending on the combination of the following `Enum`s (and perhaps some others):

- `MailItem.BodyFormat`.

  An `OlBodyFormat`, [for the body text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

  Possible values:
  `olFormatHTML`,
  `olFormatPlain`,
  `olFormatRichText`,
  `olFormatUnspecified`
- `InlineShape.Type`.

  An `WdInlineShapeType`, [for each shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.type%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

  Possible values:
  `wdInlineShapeChart`,
  `wdInlineShapeDiagram`,
  `wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject`,
  `wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine`,
  `wdInlineShapeLinkedOLEObject`,
  `wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture`,
  `wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine`,
  `wdInlineShapeLockedCanvas`,
  `wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject`,
  `wdInlineShapeOWSAnchor`,
  `wdInlineShapePicture`,
  `wdInlineShapePictureBullet`,
  `wdInlineShapePictureHorizontalLine`,
  `wdInlineShapeScriptAnchor`
- `Attachment.Type`.

  An `OlAttachmentType`, [for each attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865601%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

  Possible values:
  `olByReference`,
  `olByValue`,
  `olEmbeddeditem`,
  `olOLE`

I have examined some of these cases. The information provided is based on this limited information.

1. **Is there a comprehensive way to access IA?**

   I would say YES, with `MailItem.Inspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes` (*IA*).

   Depending on the personal definition of "attachment", there might be some items in this collection that are not regarded as such. The access is comprehensive though: there may be more items than looked for, but none is left out.
2. **Is there a comprehensive way to access BA?**

   I would say YES, with `MailItem.Attachments` (*AT*).

   I found an explanation for emails with nonempty *IA* and empty *AT*.
   They have `InlineShapes` of type `wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture`. But even in this case, there are at least two possibilities, according to [`InlineShape.Hyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.hyperlink%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

   1) There is no `Hyperlink`.
   This is the case when images are embedded, adding one item to *IA* per `InlineShape`, and at least one item to *AT* (there may be many `InlineShape`s, linked to a single `Attachment`).
   In this case, properties of [`LinkFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.linkformat%28v=office.14%29.aspx) reveal useful info, including the name of the item in *AT* related the item in *IA*.

   2) There is an `Hyperlink` (*case partly the culprit for the different findings*).
   This is the case when images are hyperlinked and not embedded. Images show up in the email, adding one item to *IA* per `InlineShape`, but they do not add items to *AT*.
   In this case, properties of `Hyperlink` and `LinkFormat` reveal useful info.

   Case 1 appears to be the standard way of attaching images ([up to Office 2013?](https://superuser.com/a/788732/245595)). Using case 2 appears to require some tweaking (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/156090/how-can-i-send-an-outlook-2007-email-containing-a-linked-image), [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/72), [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/538), and [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=word+how+to+insert+Linked+Picture)).
3. **Having a reference to an item in IA, is there any way of knowing if there is a corresponding item in AT (there may be not, according to #2), and if so identify it, IA->AT?**

   YES, at least in some cases.
   When `InlineShape.Type`=`wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture`, if there is no `InlineShape.Hyperlink` then there is an item in *AT*. It can be found by pairing `InlineShape.LinkFormat.SourceName` (up to character @) with some `Attachment.DisplayName`.
   On the other hand, I could not do this when `InlineShape.Type`=`wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject` (e.g., an inline attached Excel workbook).

I will edit with additional findings.

PS1: http://www.msoutlook.info/ has very useful info.
E.g.,
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/126,
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/205,
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/21,
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/261.

PS2: perhaps using some developers interface provides some access beyond VBA. I.e., some YESes to teh questions, which for VBA are NOs.
See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.hyperlink%28v=office.14%29.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment_members.

Answer (score 0):

The first picture is for an email in the RTF format. The attachment icons are rendered inside the message body. The second screenshot is for a plain or HTNML message. In both cases the attachments can be accessed through the MailItem.Attachments collection.

Comment: Thanks. As stated in point 2, I found cases when this is not true: non-empty `MailItem.Inspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes` collection, and empty `MailItem.attachments` collection.

Comment: How is it possible if you have a real attachment?

Comment: I don't know. But I tested with a breakpoint in a function, having in `objMsg` a reference to my `Outlook.MailItem`. In the immediate window:<br>
`? objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes.Count`<br>
` 13`<br>
`? objMsg.Attachments.Count`<br>
` 0`

Comment: And what happens when you double click on one of those 13 icons? Does Outlook open the attachment?

Comment: They are inline images. When clicked on, they open URLs, but I guess that is not because of the `Type` but because the URLs were added at the time of inserting the images.

Comment: But I have other emails with inline images that are in both collections `objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor.InlineShapes` and `objMsg.Attachments`. I have no idea what is the difference between the two emails I mention. I do not know which property/method to test that will reflect such difference. And if found, that will be the beginning of the road towards the answers to points 1-5.

Comment: Let's back off - what exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: The initial objective was finding all `InlineShape`s (and everything in the body besides text, which may take up lots of space), and replacing them by text as `<<Object removed: xxxxx>>`, `xxxxx` is the name of the file if it is stored with the `InlineShape`. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824341/outlook-vba-replace-inline-object-with-text/23830430) I managed to replace by `<<Object removed>>`; I could not get the file name. If I can associate an InlineShape with an Attachment, I think I can get the file name. Answers to questions here help, and they are useful per se.

Comment: I never tried to do that through the Word object model, but on the Extended MAPI level, RTF body places "\objattph" placeholder tags where the icons or metafile images are supposed to appear. If you do not need to show the date to the user before the message is sent, you can trap the Application.ItemSend event, read the MailItem.RtfBody property, and replace the placeholders with text.

Comment: Even though I do not fully understand your answer, I mean to use this in emails in my Inbox and other folders, not on emails to be sent. Perhaps your suggestion can be used as well. Of course, sample code is most welcome, if you have anything at hand.

Comment: You can still process the existing messages in the Inbox. I do not have any sample code that I can share, but you should be able to see the data in OutlookSpy - click IMessage button, select the PR_RTF_COMPRESSED property.

Comment: OutlookSpy looks quite comprehensive, but it would not be allowed in my corporation.