# Mass email with a customizable body with signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to mass email with a URL link to each recipient for a questionnaire they must fill out.

This is more or less the code. I receive

> Run-time error "'91' Object variable or With block not set".

Something about the Omail not being set but it has been set.

---

```vb
Sub test()
    
Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OMail
        .Display
    End With
    signature = OMail.Body
    With OMail
        .To = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        '.Attachments.Add
        .Body = "Hello world" & Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNewLine & signature
        .Send
    End With

    Set OMail = Nothing
    Set OApp = Nothing

Next

End Sub
```

I want to send multiple emails with a customizable body and I do not want to lose the signature.

Comment: You lose all rich text formatting if you do it this way, and hacking apart the underlying HTML is, frankly, a nightmare. The best (easiest) way to do this uses the WordEditor of the MailItem class, which returns a usable instance of a Word Document, and then you can manipulate it using word's object model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are these internal emails (like to everyone in your company?) or external? Your account could get flagged for spamming if they are external and you cross some threshold of emails sent since unsubscribe is not an option here. If these are external, consider using applications that have certain rules built in to avoid your account being locked.

Comment: One example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824341/outlook-vba-replace-inline-object-with-text/23830430#23830430). Basically you need to handle the word document and insert new text at the start of the document. This should be pretty trivial, I think. Good luck.

Comment: Yes this is for external emails (urdearboy), I'll look into that. And I'll look into that as well (David Zemens)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `OApp` to `Nothing` inside your loop.

Tidied up a bit:

```
Sub test()

Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OMail
        .Display
        signature = .Body
        .To = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        '.Attachments.Add
        .Body = "Hello world" & Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNewLine & signature
        .Send
    End With


    Set OMail = Nothing
    'Set OApp = Nothing '<< don't do this!

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: So it seems that this works, although now when I comment out the .Display I get rid of the signature, is there a way I can keep the signature as well as the body?