# How to change font of Active Outlook Draft

Tags: vba, outlook, font-face, font-size

This is what I am trying to do:

- Select the body of the active draft and update to Times New Roman 12pt.

  - The entire body, including other messages in the conversation, need to be included in the selection.
- I may be replying or forwarding the message so the code needs to work on the active draft.

Here are the bits of code I have been playing with.  Any suggestions will be appreciated:

```
Sub CantReadCalibri()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    
    a = TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    b = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
       
    'Code to select message body???
    
        With Selection
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Size = 12
        End With

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you try changing from `File > Options menu > Mail > Stationery and Fonts`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant


Private Sub CantReadCalibri_WholeStory()

    Dim oObj As Object
    Dim oMailEd As Object
    Dim oWord As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    
    Set oObj = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set oMailEd = oObj.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set oWord = oMailEd.Application
    Set oRng = oWord.Selection
            
    oRng.WholeStory

    With oRng
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With

End Sub


Sub CantReadCalibri_Selection()

    Dim sel As Variant
    
    Set sel = ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection
    
    With sel
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With

End Sub
```

This answer may provide an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/4368035/1571407